# What are the effects of importing an old savegame into the Witcher 2?

Tags: the-witcher, the-witcher-2

I've heard in some previews of The Witcher 2 that you can import your old The Witcher 1 savegames into the new game, similar to the way Mass Effect allows this. Is there any information on what exactly this can change in the new game?

Is it only the big decisions, like for which side you decided to fight? Or does it take more aspects of the old savegame and import them. I also remember reading that certain items and/or gold would carry over, is that confirmed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

CD Project has commented on the save imports but nothing is confirmed yet. Anyway, here are some vague points:

- Some quest- and major decisions will be carried over according to your past choices
- Characters might react differently to Geralt depending on you completed TW1 ([1](http://www.shacknews.com/article/64135/the-witcher-2-dev-diary))
- Importing some of the weapons and armor ([2](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2010-12-17-witcher-2s-insane-difficulty-revealed))
- It will impact the story, though not in a way that it changes it completely ([2](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2010-12-17-witcher-2s-insane-difficulty-revealed))
- It will **not** import your money from TW1 ([2](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2010-12-17-witcher-2s-insane-difficulty-revealed))

Comment: Couldn't add links for some reason.

Comment: New users have a limit on how many links they can insert, but you should be able to insert the links as plain text.

Comment: @Fabian: I didn't think of that... But then again I was only trying to add 2 links.

Comment: @Fabian Actually, a plain-text link would try to render as a hyperlink, so it would have to be in code formatting using backticks (`). That said, thanks to this wonderful answer, benregn now has enough reputation to make the restriction moot. Welcome to Gaming, benregn. ♪

Comment: @Grace Note: Thank you for your kind words! There are so many StackExchange sites that I'm always discovering new interesting sites. What I didn't understand that the system didn't even allow me to add two links, which it stated to be the limit for new users. Don't really get that...

Comment: @benregn It's just to prevent abuse by spammers; it's not worth gaining rep here before posting links when they can just go somewhere else without the link-posting restriction.